# Integrate Jython with Java (ImportError: No module named Crypto)

Tags: java, python, cryptography, jython

I have installed the *Jython 2.5 plugin* in *Eclipse* to integrate my *Python* code with Java but I'm getting error as `ImportError: No module named Crypto`.
I don't know how to import or add this crypto library. I want to use *AES* for some decryption mechanism, is there any jar for this *Crypto* or some process to achieve this.

Please give me hint.

Comment: Hi Ishant, you did not receive any answers on your previous questions because you forgot to use frequently viewed tags. Always at least include a tag for your language or runtime.

Comment: @owlstead i think i have tagged it..

Answer (score 1):

python crypto module uses native c code, so you cannot use it maybe.

But you can use java crypto api, instead. Refer this link below.

http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/TripleDES-encryption-in-Jython-tt5014671.html#a5015276